# What is the significance of slitting the ears of cattle in Qur'an 4:119?

Tags: shaitan, animals, surat-an-nisa

> And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and **I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle**, and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah." And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss. -- [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119)

This makes me wonder why slitting the ears of cattle has any importance.  It's certainly not something I could envisage being tempted to do, no matter how persuasive Satan is.

**Question**: What is the significance of slitting the ears of cattle in Qur'an 4:119?

Tafsir write:

> ...surely I will command them and they will cut up the cattle’s ears and this was done to the she-camels they called bahā’ir. -- [Tafsir al-Jalalayn](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=119&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)
>
> ...and surely I will command them and they will cut the cattle's ears, what is known as the Bahirah. -- [Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=119&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)

So perhaps this is an historical thing.  (It doesn't seem related to [Bahira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahira).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bahirah* was a practice of the pagan arabs of dedicating camels to their gods and marking them by slitting their ears. These were then left alone and neither ridden, nor milked, nor slaughtered, nor sheared for wool etc.

> [Quran 5:103](https://quran.com/5/103) Allah has not appointed [such innovations as] ***bahirah***
> or sa'ibah or wasilah or ham. But those who disbelieve invent
> falsehood about Allah, and most of them do not reason.

From [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.com/5:103/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir):

> As for the Bahirah, Ali bin Abi Talhah said that Ibn Abbas said, "It
> is the female camel that has given delivery five times. After that,
> they looked at the fifth delivery, if it were a male, they would
> slaughter it and give it to the men only and not the women. If it were
> a female, they would cut off its ears and proclaim, `This is a Bahirah
> ...
> (Or a Wasilah) "It is the female camel that gives delivery to a
> female and then another female at its second delivery. They would call
> such a camel a Wasilah, proclaiming that she has Wasalat (connected)
> between two females without giving birth to a male between them. So
> they used to cut off the ears of the Wasilah and let it roam free to
> pasture for their idols.

This practice was a deviation from the religion of Abraham and Ishmael, a deviation from the *fitrah*.

Answer (score 0):

Salam alaikum
Q30:30 ... there should be no change (تَبْدِيلَ) in the creation of Allah ...
Q4:119 ... desires, ... slit ears of cattle, ... change to deteriorate? (فَلَيُغَيِّرُنَّ) creation of Allah,...
As far as cattle are concerned, though all of the above answers seem to be correct, I believe there is more harm in it than we are even aware of presently. Online, there is a study regarding cattle expressing their emotions through ears; another on the harmful / painful effect of such procedures; yet another about cloning samples; and a discovery of ear regeneration of mice, ... my guess is that the negative impact of such interventions affects their emotional and subsequently physical health, which eventually reaches us (i) through the impact of the sin of hurting them, (ii) when we eat
I've been trying to study Q30:30 as to what it means for us. I've shared my learnings in a series of blogposts at: https://signsandscience.blogspot.com/

Answer (score -2):

people cut ears of cattle with their sign to sign them as their property.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion it 4.119 is referred to changing the genetic structure (genetic engineering) of animals and other species which involved taging of animals.

If you read full verse you will understand.

Now a days genetically modified seed and animals are getting very popular in the name of their productivity but this process is introducing alot of health issues as well.

Answer (score -2):

could have something in part doing with the fact cattle are being successfully cloned using dna taken from the earlobe.. and they say the same could be done with humans

Answer (score -2):

Science broadens our horizons.
Human Beings should be careful
precautions made not to cross the lines.

Genetic Modifications causes more Harm than
Good & has caused a lot obstacles in the
global world economy today.

Answer (score -3):

My tafsir on this issue is that these specific verses are dealing with Shaytan (Ch) tempting mankind to change the creation of Allah (Swt). It is widely known that modern Western scientists are taking cell samples from the ears of cattle through a small incision, a slit, to clone them and produce unnatural creatures in labs. May Allah have mercy upon us and save us from coming near to these abominations.